# How to get Bootstrap Calendar Default look using Angular Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to get Bootstrap default datepicker look and feel using Angular UI Bootstrap

Angular UI Bootstrap calendar view  :
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview`enter code here`

What I want :
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Angular UI Bootstrap project has no CSS, rather we defer directly to Bootstrap's CSS.  You can override Bootstrap's default themes or download one of the literally thousands of other BS themes out there.

You are trying to use the CSS of one project as a replacement for CSS in another.  This usually requires quite a bit of manual work.  As you can see [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/build/css), the project you want to imulate uses its own CSS.